# ChromeExtension: Storage per tab

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to store the state of my extension not in the single `chrome.storage` but per tab, the extension is about making a grid system overlay on any page and want to store the latest updates per tab here is some code:

**`popup.js`**

```
(function(){
    let gridToggleBtn = document.querySelector('#grid-toggle-btn');
    let widthInput = document.querySelector('#widthInput');
    let opacityRange = document.querySelector('#opacityRange');
    let colorPicker = document.querySelector('#colorPicker');
    let state = false;

    let chromeInject = function( key, file ) {
        chrome.tabs[key]({
            file
        });
    }

    let chromeSync = function(key, value, rebuild) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            [key]: value ? value : null,
            rebuild: state
        });
    }

    let chromeSyncCB = function(key) {
        return function() {
            chromeSync(key, this.value, true);
            chromeInject('executeScript', 'inject.js');
        }
    }

    let toggleCB = function(e){
        state = !state;
        if( state ) {
            e.currentTarget.className += ' is-on';
        } else {
            e.currentTarget.className = 'grid-toggle-btn';
        }
        chrome.storage.sync.set( {
            width: widthInput.value ? Number(widthInput.value) : null,
            opacity: opacityRange.value ? opacityRange.value : null,
            color: colorPicker.value ? colorPicker.value : null,
            rebuild: state,
            state
        } );
        chromeInject('executeScript', 'inject.js');
    }

    gridToggleBtn.onclick = toggleCB;

    gridToggleBtn.addEventListener('mousedown', chromeInject.bind(null, 'insertCSS', 'inject.css'), { once : true });


    widthInput.oninput = chromeSyncCB('width');

    opacityRange.oninput = chromeSyncCB('opacity');

    colorPicker.oninput = chromeSyncCB('color');

})();
```

**`inject.js`** the file gets injected

```
var getFromClient = () =>
    new Promise( resolve =>
        chrome.storage.sync.get( ['width', 'rebuild', 'state', 'opacity', 'color'], data => resolve( data ) ) );

var getFromClientCB = ( { width, rebuild, state, opacity, color } ) => {
    const minWidth = 320;
    const maxWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const wrapWidth = ( width < minWidth || width > maxWidth  ) ? maxWidth : width,
    base = 12,
    wrap = document.createElement('div');

    wrap.id = "gridy-wrap";
    wrap.className = width ? "gridy-wrap is-container" : "gridy-wrap";
    wrap.style.width =  wrapWidth + 'px';
    wrap.style.opacity = opacity ? opacity : 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < base; i++) {
        const col = document.createElement('div');
        col.className = `gridy-cols gridy-cols-${(i + 1)}`;
        col.style.backgroundColor = color;
        wrap.appendChild(col);
    }
    const wrapAlready = document.getElementById(wrap.id);

    if( rebuild )
    {
        if( wrapAlready ) document.body.removeChild(wrapAlready);

        document.body.appendChild(wrap);

    } else if( !state ) {
        if( wrapAlready ) {
            document.body.removeChild(wrapAlready);
        }
    }
}

getFromClient().then( getFromClientCB )
```

Comment: There's no such thing so you'll have to use the tab's URL or only the domain name as a key in storage.

Comment: You mean in this case query params?

Comment: No, the key. Currently your keys are 'width', 'rebuild', 'state', 'opacity', 'color'. Instead you will store {[new URL(tab.url).origin]: {width:1, rebuild:2, state:3, opacity:4, color:5}} and read as chrome.storage.sync.get(location.origin, data => resolve(data[location.origin]))

Comment: No it's not working like that

Comment: There is no clue for tab.url.origin

Comment: It's an example. I'm assuming you know how to get a tab's URL, otherwise you can find examples of doing that.